# Remove duplicated values in a XML document using LINQ

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq, duplicates

How I can remove duplicated values of attributes in a XML document?

This is an example XML which has 1 duplicated "Name" value as `3 Ways - Fake Love` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<!--MasterMusik Song Database-->
<Songs>
  <Song><Name>3 Ways - Fake Love</Name><Year>2000-2006</Year><Genre>Dance</Genre><Bitrate>128</Bitrate><Length>03:50</Length><Size>3,51</Size></Song>
  <Song><Name>3 Ways - Fake Love</Name><Year>2000-2006</Year><Genre>Dance</Genre><Bitrate>128</Bitrate><Length>03:50</Length><Size>3,51</Size></Song>
  <Song><Name>A7 - Piece Of Heaven</Name><Year>2000-2006</Year><Genre>Dance</Genre><Bitrate>128</Bitrate><Length>03:27</Length><Size>3,17</Size></Song>
 </Songs>
```

With this function I sort the XML elements by their "Name" values and also I try to remove duplicated names using the `Distinct` method but that does nothing.

```
Private Function Sort_XML_By_Element(ByVal XML As XDocument, _
                                 ByVal Root_Element As String, _
                                 ByVal Element_to_sort As String) As XDocument

    Dim xdoc As XDocument

    xdoc = XML
    xdoc.Root.ReplaceNodes(XML.Root.Elements(Root_Element) _
                              .OrderBy(Function(sort) sort.Element(Element_to_sort).Value).Distinct)

    Return xdoc

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554.aspx) extension method instead of `Distinct`. This method will remove all selected nodes from document. C# code:

```
xdoc.Root.Elements("Song")
    .GroupBy(s => (string)s.Element("Name"))
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)) // select all nodes from group except first one
    .Remove();
```

VB

```
xdoc.Root.<Song> _
    .GroupBy(Function(s) CStr(s.Element("Name"))) _
    .SelectMany(Function(g) g.Skip(1)) _
    .Remove()
```